# How to get number of pending message in a jms queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there any way to get count number of pending messages in jms queue. My aim is to close the connection if there is no message remaining in the queue to process. how can i achieve this.

```
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    while (true) {
        Message message = consumer.receive();

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Incoming Message:: '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Herman, You got your problem solution, Actually I am running into the same problem and I don't want to use Loop to count total number of pending messages.
Do you found any solution to get count of pending messages ?

Comment: @BhaumikSathvara please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292110/3570413

Answer (score 4):

The only reliable way to get the true Queue count form the broker is to use the [JMX MBean](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) for the Queue and call the getQueueSize method.

The other programmatic alternative is to use the [Statistics Broker Plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) which requires that you be able to change broker configuration to install it.  Once installed you can send a special message to the control queue and get a response with details for the destination you want to monitor.

Using a QueueBrowser doesn't give you a true count because the browser has a max limit on how many messages it will page into memory to send you, so if your queue is deeper than the limit you won't get the actual size, just the value of the max page size limit.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have recently started my work on Jboss fuse so i didn't have an idea of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by using createBrowser method below is my updated code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
connection.start();

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
int queueSize = QueueConsumer.getQueueSize(session, (Queue) destination);
System.out.println("QUEUE SIZE: " + queueSize);
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++) {
    Message message = consumer.receive();

    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        System.out.println("Incomming Message: '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
    }
}
connection.close();
}

private int getQueueSize(Session session, Queue queue) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
        Enumeration elems = browser.getEnumeration();
        while (elems.hasMoreElements()) {
            elems.nextElement();
            count++;
        }
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer @herman +1.Is there any hook for spring boot too?

Comment: This method only returns a count of up to the ActiveMQ "maxBrowsePageSize" configured value, anything beyond that and you are not guaranteed to get more messages even if the queue depth is greater than that amount

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with jmx it worked thanx @Tim Bish

here is my updated code

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:44444/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:1099/karaf-root");

HashMap<String, String[]> environment = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);

JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, environment);
MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

ObjectName nameConsumers = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=myqueue");
DestinationViewMBean mbView = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, nameConsumers, DestinationViewMBean.class, true);
long queueSize = mbView.getQueueSize();
System.out.println(queueSize);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just break the loop and close the connection if your JMS Message is null..

```
   while (true) {
    Message message = consumer.receive(2000);
    if (message == null){
        break;
    }
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        System.out.println("Incoming Message:: '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
     }
   }
  connection.close();
```

Comment: this didn't worked because By default consumer.receive() is blocking, which means it will wait for a message to arrive on the queue.